# не выводится элемент списка по индексу

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

В txt файле следующее содержимое:

```py
['„Admiral, diese Punkte wurden weder sorgfältig noch richtig berücksichtigt, da ich nicht anwesend war.“', 'Kirk wusste, dass seine einzige Chance jetzt darin bestand, Nogura direkt herauszufordern.', '„Und jetzt, wo ich anwesend bin, behaupte ich, dass es in Ihrer Verantwortung liegt, mich über alle negativen Argumente zu informieren, die gegen meine Auswahl vorgebracht wurden.“', 'Als Flaggoffizier und Mitarbeiter von Nogura hatte Kirk sowohl das Recht als auch die Pflicht, alles in seiner beruflichen Leistung zu erfahren, was seine Kollegen als minderwertig ansahen.', 'Noguras Augen blieben auf Kirk gerichtet, als fünf Sekunden vergingen, dann zehn ...']
```

При открытии получается строка.

```py
import ast

with open('file.txt', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    l=f.read()
    items=ast.literal_eval(l)  # Здесь содержимое перевожу в список
    
    # print(items[2])  # Этот принт не работает и не выводит элемент и выдает ошибку
    for j in items:
        print(items.index(j))
        print(items[2])  # А здесь уже выводит без ошибок
```

Выдает эту ошибку:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: У меня без ошибок ваш код отработал

Comment: Строка с ошибкой закоментирована же

Comment: да, я сделал файл как у вас в примере и раскомментировал, все отработало. Не могу сказать в чем может быть проблема, с моей стороны при дебаге `ast.literal_eval(l)` разделил элементы списка по кавычкам, в итоговом списке оказалось более, чем 3 элемента, поэтому оно без ошибки вывело элемент с индексом 2

Comment: так там и должно быть более чем 3 элемента, я само содержимое, сократил для вопроса, в оригинале, там 40 предложений, соответственно 40 элементов. и любой из 40 должен выводить

Comment: я об этом и говорю, что у меня все работает и выводит как и должно, код я не трогал. поэтому ищите проблему где-то на вашей стороне, возможно в файле, в режиме `debug` пробуйте смотреть, что приходит, как разделяется

Comment: Нужно было сделать `print(items)` и посмотреть, что напечатается. Пока выглядит как какой-то странный не воспроизводимый глюк. Как будто файл нормально не прочитался в какой-то раз. Может это было до того, как вы кодировку файла правильно указали.

Comment: Я делал print(items), печатался список. поэтому и возник вопрос почему такая ошибка

Answer (score -1):

В txt файле всегда будет формат str, поэтому вам нужно в самом файле написать сами строки(элементы массива), и каждый элемент будет в новой строке
Далее, f.readlines() будет как массив этих строк, read считывает только одну строку

Comment: `file.read()` - считывает файл целиком, а не одну строку

Answer (score -1):

Так как при чтении файла python не понимает по какому принципу ему делить строки он не может отобразить данне которые находятся внутри.

Один из вариантов получения массиса значений:

```
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
```

---

Но так же другая вариация решения данной проблемы:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as fd:
    reader = csv.reader(fd)
    for row in reader:
        # do something
```